# Match two equal values in pattern matching in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have a data type, which basically just consists of flags, e.g.:

```
data IOMode = Read | Write | ReadWrite
```

Now this would be ideal for a Semigroup, so that I could use it similiar to `enum`s in `C` (`openFile("./file", READ || WRITE)`).

```
instance Semigroup IOMode where
   ReadWrite <> _         = ReadWrite
   _         <> ReadWrite = ReadWrite
   Read      <> Write     = ReadWrite
   Read      <> Read      = Read
   Write     <> Read      = ReadWrite
   Write     <> Write     = Write
```

However is there some way to have a pattern match like:

```
(cont.)
  a          <> a         = a
```

Comment: No, Haskell only supports *linear* pattern matching.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What would be opposed to _linear_ pattern matching?

Comment: first of all it is not clear at all how two parameters *should* be equal.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Okay I guess that is true, there would be some link to an `Eq` type class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question: *no*, Haskell allows only *linear* pattern matching: this means that a variable can occur only once in the head of a clause.

## Using `Eq`

A more elegant solution is probably to let **`IOMode` derive from `Eq`**:

```
data IOMode = Read | Write | ReadWrite deriving Eq
```

and then we can use the `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> a` function, and write it as:

```
instance Semigroup IOMode where
   a         <> b         | a == b = a
   ReadWrite <> _         = ReadWrite
   _         <> ReadWrite = ReadWrite
   Read      <> Write     = ReadWrite
   Write      <> Read      = ReadWrite
```

But now a problem is that the Haskell compiler can not derive that we have covered all the cases: for the compiler `(==)` is a blackbox function, so that means that a compiler is conservative and does not know when `a == b` might fail. So perhaps we want another solution.

### Reducing the amount of rules

The above still is quite redundant, since the operator is commutative, we can first check for equality, then test against some cases, and otherwise perform a swap:

```
instance Semigroup IOMode where
   ReadWrite <> _         = ReadWrite
   Read      <> Write     = ReadWrite
   a         <> b         | a == b = a
                          | otherwise = b <> a
```

In this case, we can fold it all together, since if `a /= b`, we know that the outcome is `ReadWrite`:

```
instance Semigroup IOMode where
   a         <> b         | a == b = a
                          | otherwise = ReadWrite
```

## Using *wildcards*

Another way to handle this is to cover all the cases that are different, and use wildcards for all the cases where `a == b`:

```
instance Semigroup IOMode where
   ReadWrite <> _         = ReadWrite
   _         <> ReadWrite = ReadWrite
   Read      <> Write     = ReadWrite
   Write     <> Read      = ReadWrite
   a         <> _         = a
```

We know this will work since only the three instances that all cases where the first two parameters are different are covered by the definitions above.

We can check this by writing an instance without the wildcards (if we enable warnings):

```
Prelude Data.Semigroup| instance Semigroup IOMode where
Prelude Data.Semigroup|    ReadWrite <> _         = ReadWrite
Prelude Data.Semigroup|    _         <> ReadWrite = ReadWrite
Prelude Data.Semigroup|    Read      <> Write     = ReadWrite
Prelude Data.Semigroup|    Write     <> Read      = ReadWrite
Prelude Data.Semigroup| :}

<interactive>:22:4: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘<>’:
        Patterns not matched:
            Read Read
            Write Write
```

So Haskell has derived that there are only two patterns left: `Read Read` and `Write Write`.

Comment: You can shorten it to two statements by checking the `==` case and using `otherwise` for the rest

Comment: @Markus1189: but we use `otherwise` for the remaining parts implicitly. Of course we can perform a swap.

Comment: @4castle: yes, I had not considered the specific case. Thanks.